# Define name for tensorflow reduce_mean

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using tensorflow 2.7.1 and there I'm trying to define a name for a certain layer in my model like this:

```
tf.reduce_mean(some_other_tf, axis=1, name='my_name')
```

Later after compiling the model I want to access this layer by its name using

```
model.get_layer("my_name")
```

But it seems like there is no layer with the defined name available, the name of the particular layer is then someting like:

```
tf.math.reduce_mean_27
```

In earliert versions of tensoflow this layer was selectable using this:

```
tf_op_layer_my_name
```

How can I access such an op layer in tensorflow 2.7.1 by its defined name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `reduce_mean` is not an actual layer, just an op. You can instead use `Lambda` to define layers from functions and give them specific names. E.g.

```
mean_result = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=1),
                                     name="some_layer_name")(layer_input)
```

Now your model should have an layer that is actually named "some_layer_name" and not something else.